# C++ Inheritance (instantiating derived class inside base class)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

```
class MainClass
{
    string _ClassName;
public:
    string MainClass(string _C)
    {
        _ClassName = _C;
    }

    SubClass s1;

};

class SubClass : public MainClass
{
public:
    string Method_1()
    {
        return a;
    }
     string Method_2()
    {
        return a;
    }

};
```

Why is SubClass s1 not working can someone tell me please what am i missing I'm new to OOP.
I want to instantiate SubClass object inside MainClass but it doesn't seems to work.
basically, my aim is to access SubClass functions when MainClass object is instantiated in Main method something like this:

```
int Main()
{
  MainClass M1("test");
  M1.s1.Method_1();    <--------- this
}
```

Comment: SubClass is-a MainClass that contains a SubClass which is-a MainClass that contains a SubClass which is-a MainClass ...

Comment: Good point, I didn't even spot that.

Comment: your idea of inheritance is the wrong way around. A `MainClass` is a `MainClass`, while the `SubClass` inherits methods from `MainClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is, that the MainClass does not know a thing about SubClass when you're trying to instantiate the object.

You need to use a forward declaration and a pointer to make it work.

Header file:

```
class SubClass;    //Forward declaration, allows pointer.
class MainClass
{
    string _ClassName;
public:
    MainClass(string _C); //No return type on constructor
    ~MainClass();

    SubClass *s1;    //Size: 4 Bytes on 32bit system

    protected:
        MainClass();

};

class SubClass : public MainClass
{
public:
    string Method_1();
    string Method_2();
};
```

CPP file:

```
#include "headerFile.h"

MainClass::MainClass(string _C) : 
    _ClassName(_C),
    s1(new SubClass)    //Class definition is now known.
{
}

MainClass::MainClass() : s1(nullptr)    //Nullptr -> No new object, no infinite recursion.
{
}

MainClass::~MainClass() 
{
    delete s1;    //Do not forget to clean up your pointer.
}

string SubClass::Method_1()
{
    return "a";
}

string SubClass::Method_2()
{
    return "a";
}
```

Call:

```
int main()
{
  MainClass M1("test");
  M1.s1->Method_1();    //-> to dereference the pointer.
}
```

The second problem, as Richard Critten has pointed out, is an infinite recursion, which will cause your program to crash very quickly.

Each time you instantiate a SubClass, you also create a subclass, which creates yet another MainClass etc.

To circumvent this, you'll need a protected constructor, which does NOT create the subclass member.

The third problem:
You are returning `a` in your methods, which suggests a variable.
If you meant to return 'a', you need to put them into quotation marks.

Finally, in order to get it to compile, you'll need to write `Main` with a small `m` (`int main()`), otherwise the linker will complain.

However, as Mr. 'Not a number' correctly stated, the above edits only make your code compile.

What you likely are actually after however would be using `virtual` functions, which can be overridden by sub classes to specialize the behavior.

An example code using actual inheritance:

Header file:

```
class MainClass
{
    string _ClassName;
public:
    MainClass(string _C); //No return type on constructor
    virtual ~MainClass();    //All base classes that have at least one virtual method should also have a virtual destructor, even if it is empty.

    virtual void doSomething();
};

class SubClass : public MainClass
{
    public:
        SubClass(string className);
        void doSomething();
};
```

CPP file:

```
#include "headerFile.h"
#include <stdio.h>

MainClass::MainClass(string _C) : _ClassName(_C)
{
}

MainClass::~MainClass()
{}

void MainClass::doSomething()
{
    printf("Called from MainClass\n");
}

SubClass::SubClass(string className) : MainClass(className)
{
}

void SubClass::doSomething()
{
    printf("Called from SubClass\n");
}
```

Call:

```
int main()
{
    MainClass M1("test");
    SubClass sub("SubClass");
    MainClass *pointer = &sub;

    M1.doSomething();         //Outputs 'Called from MainClass'.
    sub.doSomething();        //Outputs 'Called from SubClass'.
    pointer->doSomething();   //Also outputs 'Called from SubClass', since it points to sub and because sub overrides the behaviour from MainClass.
}
```

To call the parent method from the child method, you need to invoke the method from within the override with the parent class.

Example (in SubClass::doSomething): `MainClass::doSomething()`.

Comment: you made the code compile, but I dont think this is what OP was aiming for. Btw it wont crash at runtime, but it wont compile

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, ran the thing through a compiler, fixed the obvious problems and added an example on how to achieve actual inheritance.
You were right, did not take the likely intent of the OP's question into account.

Comment: thnks that really helped me a lot but i figured for what i wanna achieve i'm well of with just creating a structure and instantiating it inside the main class , M1.s1.Method_1();       works in the main() just as i wanted.

Comment: @Aveloni, I'm glad I was able to help a little. If you consider the problem solved, please mark the answer as 'accepted' (the checkmark beneath the score). This will tell everyone else, that you don't need help any more.